# C : Process keeps exiting before being able to input anything

Tags: c, char, c-strings, strcmp, toupper

I'm having trouble with my code below. Before I could input a response [y/n], it just exits the program. I don't see any errors in my compiler so I'm having a hard time fixing this.

```
   srand(time(NULL));  
    int nGid; //guest id
    char opt1;
    printf(" Hello Guest! do you have an id number [Y/N]?");
    scanf("%c", &opt1);

    opt1 = toupper(opt1);
  //asks for guest id
    if (strcmp(opt1, 'Y') == 0){
        printf("Please enter id: \n");
        scanf("%d", &nGid);
    }
  //generates random id number
    else {
        nGid = rand()%100;
        printf("Your guest id is : %d", nGid);
  return 0;
}
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: OT: `strcmp()` expects two *pointers* to a `0`-terminated `char`-array, that is two `char*`. The code passes two `char`. Take the compiler's warnings serious.

Comment: To compare two characters just to `opt1 == 'Y' `.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` takes null terminated `char *`, but you are passing `char` as arguments.

You can directly compare two `char` using `==` operator.

Change.

```
if (strcmp(opt1, 'Y') == 0){
```

to

```
if (opt1 == 'Y'){
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this statement

```
scanf("%c", &opt1);
```

use

```
scanf(" %c", &opt1);
       ^^^
```

In general instead of

```
opt1 = toupper(opt1);
```

it would be correctly to write

```
opt1 = toupper( ( unsigned char )opt1);
```

Otherwise the function call can have undefined behavior.

The variable `opt1` has the type char. It can not contain a string. So you may not apply the standard function `strcmp` that deals with strings. Just write

```
if ( opt1 == 'Y' ){
```

Comment: Out of curiousity: Why would the cast of `opt1` prevent undefined behaviour? `opt1` is of type `char` already and will implicitely be promoted to `int`, so why the cast?

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous If the type char behaves as the type signed char then due to the integer promotions the integer value in general can be negative and the call of toupper results in undefined behavior.